# How to dynamically change Vuex store values

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, state, vuex

I was trying to find a way to be able to use `Vue.set()` to dynamically alter bound data within Vuex store. However it has proven to be difficult to find, so I tried a few ways to figure out my own solution and finally this is what has worked.
Its pretty disgusting so viewer discretion is advised.

This is what my solution atm is:

```
  mutations: {
    add_to_store(state, [route, key, value]){
      const call_vue_set_with_dinamic_params = new Function(
        "Vue",
        "state",
        "route",
        "key",
        "value",
        `Vue.set(state${route === "" ? "" : `.${route}`}, key, value)`
      );

      call_vue_set_with_dinamic_params(Vue, state, route, key, value)
    }
  }
```

I thought it might be a fun exercise for anyone with some time on his/her hands, to try and optimize it, because I am personally a bit lost.
I have tried passing the found object into `Vue.set()`, like so:

```
const create_nested_object = ( base, names ) => {
  names.split(".").forEach(name => {
    base = base[ name ] = base[ name ] || {}
  })
  return base
}

mutations: {
  add_to_store(state, [route, key, value]){  
    Vue.set(
      create_nested_object(state, route),
      key,
      value
    )
  }
}
```

But that hasnt worked. I also tried just overwriting the whole `state` with a newly created `state`, which did overwrite it, but has stopped it from being reactive.

Basically what the mutation should be able to do is take a string with the route to the wanted object like: `user.hair.color` and change it to desired value.
Purpose is to not have to create a mutation for each key separately.

Answer (score 0):

I did not try it, but this should work. You iterate over the route keys and keep a reference of the finally nested object and pass it to your `Vue.set`

```
const create_nested_object = ( base, names ) => {
  let ref = base
  names.split('.').forEach(name => {
    ref = ref[name]
  })

  return ref
}

mutations: {
  add_to_store(state, [route, key, value]){
    Vue.set(
      create_nested_object(state, route),
      key,
      value
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this as well, that throws a JS error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'defaults' in undefined` because the Vue.set() function uses `if (key in target && !(key in Object.prototype))` to go through the object.

Comment: Try with `this._vm.$set` instead of `Vue.set` this seem to work on my computer

Comment: Gives me `this._vm.$set.set is not a function`

Comment: My bad, it seems it was not the `Vue.set` that was problematic, but I got it to work, [see this codepen for a working example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ErjYrj?editors=1111).